# Issue with HYPERLINK

Tags: excel, vba, macos

It is probably a very small thing I am missing, but I can't seem to spot the issue.

```vb
Sub sendemail()

'Save the form with todays date
Application.Save Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy") & ".xls"

'Create the email
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim strbody As String

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

strbody = "<HTML><BODY>"
strbody = strbody & "<A href= http://ne-xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.biz/ASP/SFP/BHGP/xxUK-OPS/Shared%20Documents/xxx/AllItems.aspx?RootFolder=%2fAxP%2fASP%2fBP%2fNUK%2dOPS%2fShared%20Documents%2f60%2e%20Shift%20Schedule&FolderCTID=&View=%7b1A03DBA9%2d7CEB%2d466F%2d8EA8%2dDDE03D95CDC0%7d>URL</A>"
strbody = strbody & "</BODY></HTML>"
On Error Resume Next

With OutMail
    .To = "[xxxx@xx]"
    .cc = ""
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = "New Holiday Request on " & Format(Now(), "dd/mm/yyyy") & " by " & Range("C2") & ""
    .Body = strbody
    .Send

End With
On Error GoTo 0
Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing
Debug.Print strbody

End Sub
```

End result should just be a hyperlink in an email...but it's displaying:

http://ne-xxx.xxxx.xxx.xxxx.xxx/sSP/SXP/BJHJP/xxx-OPS/Shared%20Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx?RootFolder=%2fASP%2fSsP%2foP%2fNBXUK%2dOPS%2fShared%20Documents%2f60%2e%20Shift%20Schedule&FolderCD=&View=%7b1A03DBA9%2d7CEB%2d466F%2d8EA8%2dDDE03D95CDC0%7d>URL

Comment: try wrapping the url in apostrophies

Comment: You'll need to double the quotes, href=""http:///...""

Comment: doesnt seem to be working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please use below code block

```
strbody = strbody & "<A href=""http://ne-xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.biz/ASP/SFP/BHGP/xxUK-OPS/Shared%20Documents/xxx/AllItems.aspx?RootFolder=%2fAxP%2fASP%2fBP%2fNUK%2dOPS%2fShared%20Documents%2f60%2e%20Shift%20Schedule&FolderCTID=&View=%7b1A03DBA9%2d7CEB%2d466F%2d8EA8%2dDDE03D95CDC0%7d"">URL</A>"       

.HTMLBody = strbody instead of Body
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
.Body = strbody
```

to

```
.HTMLBody = strbody
```

My sample vbs code worked with or without the quotes

```
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

strbody = "<HTML><BODY>"
strbody = strbody & "<A href=http://ne-xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.biz/ASP/SFP/BHGP/xxUK-OPS/Shared%20Documents/xxx/AllItems.aspx?RootFolder=%2fAxP%2fASP%2fBP%2fNUK%2dOPS%2fShared%20Documents%2f60%2e%20Shift%20Schedule&FolderCTID=&View=%7b1A03DBA9%2d7CEB%2d466F%2d8EA8%2dDDE03D95CDC0%7d>URL</A>"
strbody = strbody & "</BODY></HTML>"

With OutMail
    .To = "pankaj.jaju@stackoverflow.com"
    .HTMLBody = strbody
    .Send
End With

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing
```